# Integration within 4 defining lines

Tags: integration

This is a problem I encountered recently, that I just couldn't solve. Can anybody help me out?

Sketch the region enclosed by these curves. Integrate to find the area enclosed by the curves.

$$y=x^2,\ \ y=6x^2,\ \ 5x+y=6,\ \ x \geq 0$$

It might not seem hard at first, but just try graphing it.

Comment: Where is the difficulty of that? Just draw $y=x^2$, $y=6x^2$ and $y=6-5x$ for $x>0$ (and, say $x<3$). Also, the tag "integration" might be wrong for this question.

Comment: http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: I forgot to include the part telling you to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  For what values of $x > 0$ is it true that $x^2 \le 6 - 5x \le 6x^2$?